# deselectRowAtIndexPath: failing in iOS5

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, xcode4

The following works fine in iOS 4.3 but throws a EXC_BAD_ACCESS in iOS5.

```
if(mainTable != nil){
    [mainTable deselectRowAtIndexPath:currentIndexPath animated:YES];
```

mainTable is of type UITableView.  It fails on the row with deselectRowAtIndexPath:. The above exception occurs when leaving the main (first) table view.  The steps are: Click a row from main table view.  Another table view displays.  Click top left button to go back to the main table and exception occurs.

Actually, by the time

```
 - (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
```

is hit via breakpoint, currentIndexPath is already released in iOS5.

What can I look for here?  I know iOS5 does some different things with releasing objects.  Perhaps there are some additional checks I can do but I'm not sure where to start.

EDIT:
It is defined as

```
currentCellIndex = indexPath;
```

and comes from

```
-(void) displaySubView:(UITableView *)tableView indexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I do have zombies enabled in the Run part of my scheme and now get the details.  When I hit the above line, I see in the console:

```
*** -[NSIndexPath isEqual:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x85a2010
```

Why does that happen in iOS5 and not in iOS 4.3?  I do have a breakpoint in the dealloc on currentIndexPath and it is never hit.

I'm starting to believe this is related to ARC.  I still have lots of retains/releases.  I don't want to do the auto format for ARC since that is to cause more problems.  I did try the flag used to disable ARC on a per file basis.  That just threw a compiler error with unknown command.

Comment: How are you getting currentIndexPath?

Comment: One place to start would be to enable zombies:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386160/how-to-enable-nszombie-on-xcode-4

Comment: better link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190227/how-do-i-set-nszombieenabled-in-xcode-4

Comment: Zombies enabled and more details in edit on OP.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848137/debugging-over-released-objects-problem-with-nszombie/4848483#4848483

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an exact answer to your question, but you might want to consider deselecting your row in `viewWillAppear`:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [mainTable deselectRowAtIndexPath:[mainTable indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];
}
```

You need to implement this in the 'parent' view controller, where `mainTable` is declared.

Regarding your actual question, can you tell us how does your `@property` look for `currentCellIndex`?

Comment: I will try what you mentioned but unfortunately, this error is blocking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836849/xcode-looking-in-wrong-folder.  This project has really gone south with iOS5.