# Xcode looking in wrong folder

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4

Xcode 4.2 is looking in my tags folder when I build.  This is causing duplicate interface errors, since it believe I have defined classes twice.  My folder structure is:

- tags
- trunk

My current build is in trunk and Xcode is also looking in tags.  How can I make it stop doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After editing the pbxproj file, I found references into the other folder.  I then removed those files via Xcode and added them back from the correct location.  Problem solved.